# Would virtual memory be still a useful memory management scheme if the amount of physical memory is bigger than amount of virtual memory?

Tags: memory-management, virtual

Being asked this in my homework.

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: The direction you want to go with this is to ask what virtualization of memory provides. Is it just the ability to use disk as very slow RAM or do you get other benefits. If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

Without virtual memory, you couldn't have something as simple as `fork` without having to swap processes in and out on every task switch (because they'd be using the same physical memory addresses). You also couldn't memory map files or fault-load executables. So yes, virtual memory would still be useful even if not being used to permit more virtual memory than physical memory.